# UIKit: Is it possible to make a category for UIKeyboard?

Tags: ios, uikit, uikeyboard, uiwindow

I want to make a category on `UIKeyboard`, but I get the error, "Cannot find interface declaration for UIKeyboard`. But, when I try to give it an interface declaration, I get a warning that it's already defined by UIKit. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *public* definition for UIKeyboard, hence you cannot add a category to it because adding a category to a class requires access to it's interface header.